# VSCode Web+Server Loading Screen

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to deploy a VSCode Web+Server instance into an AWS Cluster. I've managed to do it, but it takes like up to 10s to load all the JS Files and while I'm waiting for this there is just a blank screen. It's there a way to enable/add a spinner or something similar while the user it's waiting?

I've looked through the documentation and the [VSCode source code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode)  and I did not find anything relevant

Comment: Can you add steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Just run the code-server script, and you will see it. (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/scripts/code-server.sh)

Comment: Had the same problem while running an on premise VSCode instance